# Autofill to new last row from previously last row after data is added?

Tags: vba, excel, autofill

I have a database that is growing quite large. Every day I add about 100 rows of information.

I have about 20 columns that autofill with calculations, etc. A few of those columns pull from a VERY large file using `Vlookup`s. That takes forever because it's pulling the entire column everyday because my current autofill macro starts in row 2.

Is there any way to write the macro so that it autofills from the previous "last row" so it's only autofilling 100 or so new rows instead of several thousand?

I have tried the following with no luck:
`Range("BZ2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("BZ2:BZ" & LastRow)` is an example of one of my VBA codes for an autofill I use. `LastRow` is the last row after the new data is pasted in. I would like it to ideally start at the `OldLastRow` which would be the last row before I paste in the new data. I tried `Range("BZ" & OldLastRow).AutoFill Destination:=Range("BZ" & OldLastRow & ":BZ" & LastRow)` without luck.

Comment: You could use Selection.End(xlUp).Select I suppose. Pick a range below a column with data and step up to the last row and store it in a variable. Go to a column where you want to autofill and pick a range far below and step up, store that address in a variable. Then you could always use offset(0,1) and so on.

Comment: How would I implement that to work with the autofill?  My problem is that the autofill seemingly won't let me use a variable to replace the actual number of the cell I want to start in.  So BZ2 works but BZ & OldLastRow does not.

Comment: Or apparently it did start working.  I guess I had something small off like a period or IDK what was wrong...lol

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    Dim LastRow As Long

    With ActiveSheet
'This will get you the OldLastRow. Add +1 to the end to get the first empty row if you need it.
'The "A" in .Rows.Count, "A" should be replaced with a column that will always have data in every row.
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("BZ2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("BZ2:BZ" & LastRow)
'This will pause the macro until Calculations are complete.
        Do While Application.CalculationState <> xlDone
            DoEvents
        Loop
    End With
```

Ideally you would be doing the autofill from the point that you pasted your data in, so you wouldnt want to have "BZ2" anywhere in there if you just want to autofill new data.

you could try this one as well.

```
Dim LastRow As Long

With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "BZ").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("BZ2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("BZ" & LastRow & ":BZ" & Cells(Rows.Count, "BY").End(xlUp).Row)
    Do While Application.CalculationState <> xlDone
        DoEvents
    Loop
End With

This is assuming you only have one column of calculations. if not change the "BZ" & LastRow & ":BZ" to "BZ" & LastRow & ":CA" or whatever your last calculated column is.
```